# Arduino Laser light detection - Photoresistor or Laser sensor module?

Tags: sensors

I understand you can use either a basic photoresistor or this non-modulated laser sensor. But which is more reliable for basic light detection?

I am wanting to detect the beam from a basic laser pen. With simple On/Off trigger rather than detecting intensity.

Laser Sensor: [Sensor Module Link](https://www.ebay.co.uk/i/264530525656?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=710-134428-41853-0&mkcid=2&itemid=264530525656&targetid=595344343570&device=c&mktype=pla&googleloc=1007239&poi=&campaignid=6619151966&mkgroupid=84510980808&rlsatarget=aud-381667280803:pla-595344343570&abcId=1140496&merchantid=137612688&gclid=CjwKCAiAzuPuBRAIEiwAkkmOSFVdvlt2NcO_HMLYjpaLmELb99iliZMoFXpxc2oTAb41KZOl4ZlRvxoCOdsQAvD_BwE)

The laser sensor board shows a DS18820 sensor.

Comment: My initial thought is the Photoresistor might be accidentally triggered by ambient light but the module is more stable and will only detect direct laser light.

Comment: your post doesn't make any sense to me as an engineer. you do not specify reliabilty. you can turn any "intensity" measurement into on/off using a threshold. also please note that this is a programming community. your post is off-topic as you're asking for hardware advise.

Comment: use regular LED as a detector, much faster than photo resistor